# Modifying PathRules of a UrlPathMap of an application gateway

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-gateway

I need to add and remove PathRules of a URL path map dynamically from code via Azure SDK for .NET
Currently I work with following nuget package [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/1.36.1).
I couldn't see any ways to accomplish this. I can only retrieve the available values via `IApplicationGateway.Inner.UrlPathMaps.PathRules`

I basically want this: [How to update Azure Application Gateway Path Based Rule UrlPathMap from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756000/how-to-update-azure-application-gateway-path-based-rule-urlpathmap-from-net)
But not via Azure CLI or PowerShell.

I was expecting something similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/url-path-map?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update Azure Application Gateway with the package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent`, please refer to the following steps

1. create a service principal and assign `Contributor` role to the sp

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --sdk-auth
```

2. Code

```
string clientId = "";
            string clientSecret = "";
            string tenantId = "";
            string subscriptionId = "";
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
                    clientSecret,
                    tenantId,
                    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

            var groupName = "testgateway";
            var name = "gateway";
            var restClient =RestClient.Configure()
                .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                .WithCredentials(credentials)
                .Build();
            NetworkManagementClient networkClient = new NetworkManagementClient(restClient);
            networkClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
            var gateway = await networkClient.ApplicationGateways.GetAsync(groupName, name);
            ApplicationGatewayUrlPathMapInner[] rules = gateway.UrlPathMaps.ToArray();
            // update one rule 
            foreach (ApplicationGatewayUrlPathMapInner rule in rules) {
               var pathRule= rule.PathRules.ToArray().Where(item => item.Name == "Video").FirstOrDefault();
                pathRule.Paths = new List<string> { "/myvideo/*" };
            }

           await networkClient.ApplicationGateways.CreateOrUpdateAsync(groupName, name, gateway);
```

[image]